# ASP.NET CustomValidator with ClientValidationFunction not Firing if validation fails

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

I am validating date using customvalidator but this is not working well can any one tell why

This is my .aspx

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;
    months += d2.getMonth();
    return months;
}

function difference(d1,d2){

var hiredate,dob;
var diff=18*12;
hiredate=document.getElementById(d1).value;
dob=document.getElementById(d2).value;
var months=monthDiff(hiredate,dob);
if(diff<=months)
{
return true;
//true
}
else
{
return false;
//false
}
}

function validatehiredate(value, arg) {
                arg.IsValid = (difference('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtHiredate','ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDateofBirth'));
            }
</script>

 <asp:TextBox id="txtHiredate" runat="server" />
 <asp:TextBox id="txtDateofBirth" runat="server" />
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="validatehiredate" ControlToValidate="txtDateofBirth" ValidationGroup="personal" Display="Dynamic" ValidateEmptyText="True">can not hire guy less than 18 yrs</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Can any one tell what's wrong in this

Comment: If i select or give the dates in equal it is not firing any validation

Comment: So it never fires off the validation, or it only fires off the validation when the dates are not the same?

Comment: Have you tried it without the validation group?

Comment: It is not firing for any ya i used validation group too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your monthDiff function to the below:

```
 function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
        var months;
        var date1 = new Date(d1);
        var date2 = new Date(d2);

        months = (date2.getFullYear() - date1.getFullYear()) * 12;
        months -= date1.getMonth() + 1;
        months += date2.getMonth(); return months;
       }
```

you can't use the `getFullYear` or `getMonth` on anything other than date objects.

I am going to make the assumption that you're browser is throwing a javascript error, it's just not popping up

**EDIT**

```
        function getDays(d1, d2) {
            var months;
            var date1 = new Date(d1);
            var date2 = new Date(d2);
            return (date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
            return months;
        }

        //function getLeapYear

        function difference(d1, d2) 
        {
            var hiredate, dob; var diff = 18 * 12;
            hiredate = document.getElementById(d1).value;
            dob = document.getElementById(d2).value;
            var Age = getDays(hiredate, dob);
            var compareVal = 365 * 18; //getCompareVal(hiredate,dob);

            if (Age >= compareVal) {
                return true;
                //true
            } else {
                return false; //false
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey but if i select age greater than 18 it is firing too

Comment: I think it is also necessary to change in year function too can u check once

Comment: TBohnen.jnr Hi dude are you there

Comment: yes sorry, I am looking into changing how you do it, at the moment you are only using the year as well as the month, If you use a more exact method it should be better, will update code now

Comment: ok, so change your monthDiff with my getdays and then also update the difference function. The only problem with this is you still need to subtract the leap years, which i will create a function for now

Comment: Thanks a lot if any issues i will let you know

Comment: `@TBohnen.jnr` i need small help if i would like to do the same for another like if i have 2 dates and if i select date as some `1-3-2011` in one text box and if i select other as 31-12-2010` it should raise an error how can i do this please help